# Conditional Statement logged in user

Tags: wordpress, if-statement

> I want to create a conditional statement that if the logged in user is an employee/candidate the button should display User page. The code below doesn't work.

```
<ul class="float-right">
<?php if($minicart_status) {  get_template_part( 'inc/mini_cart'); } 
if ( is_user_logged_in() && current_user_can("employee" || "candidate")) { 
    if( ! empty( $loginpage )) { 
        $loginlink = get_permalink($loginpage);
        if($user_page_status){  ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url(apply_filters('workscout_woo_userpage', $loginlink)); ?>"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> <?php esc_html_e('User Page','workscout') ?></a>
        </li>
        <?php }
        } ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url() );  ?>"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> <?php esc_html_e('Log Out','workscout') ?></a></li>
</ul>
```

> I want to create a conditional statement that if the logged in user is an administrator the button should display Admin page

```
<ul class="float-right">
<?php if($minicart_status) {  get_template_part( 'inc/mini_cart'); } 
if ( is_user_logged_in() && current_user_can("administrator")) { 
    if( ! empty( $loginpage )) { 
        $loginlink = get_permalink($loginpage);
        if($user_page_status){  ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url(apply_filters('workscout_woo_userpage', $loginlink)); ?>"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> <?php esc_html_e('Admin Page','workscout') ?></a>
        </li>
        <?php }
        } ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url() );  ?>"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> <?php esc_html_e('Log Out','workscout') ?></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your OR condition, you should call the current_user_can function twice, you can't user OR inside that function:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() && (current_user_can("employee") || current_user_can("candidate")) ) { 
}
```